# yValue is out of chart using the dygraphs library

Tags: dygraphs

I'm using Dygraph library.

[image: Dygraph]

See picture, why "$0.00" is out of the chart?
Here is my code:

```js
new Dygraph(document.getElementById("graphdiv"),
            $scope.dataPrediction,
            {
                errorBars: true,
                animatedZooms: false,
                customBars: true,
                legend: 'always',
                labelsSeparateLines: true,
                axisLabelFontSize: '12',
                labels: ["x", "Current costs", "Predicted cost by switching to reserved instance"],
                labelsDivWidth: "440",
                colors: ["#1f77b4", "#ff9f4a"],
                axes: {
                    y: {
                        axisLabelFormatter: function (y) {
                            return "$" + y.toFixed(2);
                        },
                        valueFormatter: function (y) {
                            return "$" + y.toFixed(2);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that's Dygraph optimising the view based on the data it has.

There is an option [includeZero](http://dygraphs.com/options.html#includeZero) that should fix this